Class TFDConnection not found
I am trying to create a simple Rad Server with delphi.  I started by adding a Datamodule for database connection. It does connect and work, Created a singleton so other data modules could use the connection.  When I run and the connection is called, I get error TFDConnection not found.
This is my db connection module
    unit databaseConnection;
 
interface
 
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.JSON,
  EMS.Services, EMS.ResourceAPI, EMS.ResourceTypes, FireDAC.Stan.Intf,
  FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf, FireDAC.Phys.Intf,
  FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async, FireDAC.Phys,
  FireDAC.Phys.MySQL, FireDAC.Phys.MySQLDef, FireDAC.ConsoleUI.Wait,
  FireDAC.Phys.MSSQLDef, FireDAC.Phys.ODBCBase, FireDAC.Phys.MSSQL, Data.DB,
  FireDAC.Comp.Client;
 
type
  [ResourceName('DatabaseConnection')]
  TDatabaseConnectionResource1 = class(TDataModule)
  private
    class var FInstance: TDatabaseConnectionResource1; // Singleton instance
  public
    FDConnection1: TFDConnection;
    FDPhysMSSQLDriverLink1: TFDPhysMSSQLDriverLink;
    class function Instance: TDatabaseConnectionResource1;
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
    procedure BeforeDestruction; override;
 
  published
  end;
 
implementation
 
{%CLASSGROUP 'System.Classes.TPersistent'}
 
{$R *.dfm}
 
{ TDatabaseConnectionResource1 }
 
class function TDatabaseConnectionResource1.Instance: TDatabaseConnectionResource1;
begin
  if FInstance = nil then
    FInstance := TDatabaseConnectionResource1.Create(nil);
  Result := FInstance;
end;
 
procedure TDatabaseConnectionResource1.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  // Initialization code if needed
end;
 
procedure TDatabaseConnectionResource1.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  // Clean-up code if needed
  inherited;
end;
 
procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterResource(TypeInfo(TDatabaseConnectionResource1));
end;
 
initialization
  Register;

Now in the next module I have added the unit to the uses
uses ... databaseConnection;

Now I try to connect connection to query below.
// Initialize query
    LQuery := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
    try
      LQuery.Connection := TDatabaseConnectionResource1.Instance.FDConnection1;
 
      // Insert new user
      LSQL := 'INSERT INTO Teams (Company, Status, admin_rank, phone) VALUES (:Company, :Status, :Admin_Rank, :Phone)';
      LQuery.SQL.Text := LSQL;
      LQuery.ParamByName('Company').AsString := LCompany;
      LQuery.ParamByName('Status').AsString := LStatus;
      LQuery.ParamByName('Admin_Rank').AsInteger := Ladminrank;
      LQuery.ParamByName('Phone').AsString := LPhone;
      LQuery.ExecSQL;
 
      AResponse.StatusCode := 200; // OK
      AResponse.Body.SetValue(TJSONString.Create('Team created successfully'), True);
    finally
      LQuery.Free;
    end;
  finally
    LJSON.Free;
  end
  else
  begin
    AResponse.RaiseBadRequest('Invalid JSON');
  end;

everything compiles and builds, but can not seem to find why its giving this error? Am I missing something?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355371/component-build-required-package-used-for-tfdconnection-not-found does this help?

@Ineffable21 I thought it would , but can tell what the solution was,  seems it was to add the firedac.comp.client  which i all ready have.

Have you tried adding FireDAC.Comp.Client to the uses clause of your second module as well? You state that currently you only have it in uses clause of your databaseConnection module.

RAD Server creates instances of its modules in several threads. A singleton just doesn't look right in this scenario.

@SilverWarior yes it's in both.

@UweRaabe it seem better then each module having it's own connections as I will have about 30-40 of them.  Would you suggest a better way?

Fact is that RAD Server creates a thread for each connection and also creates the datamodules to serve this connection inside this thread. TFDConnection can only be used from one thread at a time. I suggest reading the docs about FireDAC multi-threading.

@UweRaabe so I need to add a fdmanager and make pooling true? Is this what you are suggesting?

That sounds way more plausible.

As @UweRaabe said, every request (thread) should be serviced by a separate connection (if you try to run multiple SQL commands on the same connection, at the same time, you will get AVs), and the best way to achieve that is with pooling those connections. Here you have an example https://blogs.embarcadero.com/using-firedac-connection-pooling-with-rad-server/ I'm using RAD Server this way and runs like a charm.
